# How to do a release/deploy build of a clojurescript app?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cljsbuild

I'm ready to release my clojurescript app. Currently i do `lein ring uberjar` to create my jar, which does build cljs, but i dont see any documentation on how to do a release build-- do i need to do any concat-ing/minifying/bla bla bla? Are there special release options?

Here is my cljsbuild setup in my project.clj->

```
{
          :builds [{:id            "dev"
                    :source-paths  ["src/analyticsjs"]
                    :figwheel      false
                    :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["resources/public/js/compiled" "target"]
                    :compiler      {:main       "analyticsjs.core"
                                    :asset-path "/js"
                                    :output-to  "resources/public/js/cljs.js"
                                    :output-dir "resources/public/js"}}
                   ]

          }
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was directed in the [clojurians slack channel](http://clojurians.net/) to add `:optimizations :advanced` inside my `:compiler` map, which worked.

Comment: You should accept your own answer there's not much else to it.